# "TypeError: t is not a function" while working with updating the `react-data-table-component` package

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, styled-components, react-data-table-component

While I was updating my `react-data-table-component` package, I faced some console errors saying 'TypeError: t is not a function'. There doesn't seem any help available in the package docs or the discussion forum with this particular error. I have upgraded my package from `^6.11.6` to `^7.6.2`.

Here is a screenshot of the console errors,
[image: Console Errors]

Here is my code which utilizes the Datatable component,

```
/* eslint-disable react/forbid-prop-types */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import Error from '../Error/Error';
import GeneralUtil from '../../utils/general';
import AssetUtil from '../../utils/asset';
import styles from './ProjectNotes.css';

const columns = [
  {
    name: 'Type',
    selector: 'type',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'URI',
    selector: 'uri',
    sortable: true,
    grow: 3,
    wrap: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Date/Time',
    selector: 'updated',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Author',
    selector: 'author',
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Note',
    selector: 'content',
    sortable: true,
    grow: 3,
    wrap: true,
    // Only way I could figure out to get it to prioritize my white-space CSS setting.
    cell: row => (
      <span style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap', paddingBottom: '5px', paddingTop: '5px' }}>
        {row.content}
      </span>
    )
  }
];

const TextField = styled.input`
  height: 32px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 0 32px 0 16px;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

const ClearButton = styled.button`
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
const FilterComponent = ({ filterText, onFilter, onClear }) => (
  <>
    <TextField
      id="search"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search notes"
      aria-label="Search Input"
      value={filterText}
      onChange={onFilter}
    />
    <ClearButton type="button" onClick={onClear}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="times" size="sm" />
    </ClearButton>
  </>
);

const projectNotes = props => {
  const [filterText, setFilterText] = React.useState('');
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(true);
  const [feed, setFeed] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const subHeaderComponentMemo = React.useMemo(() => {
    const handleClear = () => {
      if (filterText) {
        setFilterText('');
      }
    };

    return (
      <FilterComponent
        onFilter={e => setFilterText(e.target.value)}
        onClear={handleClear}
        filterText={filterText}
      />
    );
  }, [filterText]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPending(false);

    if (props.project) {
      let mappedProjectNotes = [];
      if (props.project.notes) {
        mappedProjectNotes = props.project.notes.map(n => {
          return { type: 'Project', updated: n.updated, author: n.author, content: n.content };
        });
      }

      let mappedAssetNotes = [];
      if (props.project.assets) {
        mappedAssetNotes = AssetUtil.getAllNotes(props.project.assets).map(n => {
          return {
            type: 'Asset',
            uri: n.uri,
            updated: n.updated,
            author: n.author,
            content: n.content
          };
        });
      }

      const mappedPersonNotes = [];
      if (props.project.people) {
        props.project.people.forEach(p => {
          if (p && p.notes) {
            p.notes.forEach(n =>
              mappedPersonNotes.push({
                type: 'Person',
                uri: GeneralUtil.formatName(p.name),
                updated: n.updated,
                author: n.author,
                content: n.content
              })
            );
          }
        });
      }

      // If any of our notes collections are set, build up a combined collection
      // of the notes.  Otherwise set the feed explicitly to null so we know to
      // render it as empty.
      if (
        mappedAssetNotes.length > 0 ||
        mappedProjectNotes.length > 0 ||
        mappedPersonNotes.length > 0
      ) {
        setFeed([...mappedProjectNotes, ...mappedAssetNotes, ...mappedPersonNotes]);
      } else {
        setFeed(null);
      }
      return;
    }
    setFeed(null);
  }, [props.project]);

  let contents = <div className={styles.empty}>There are no notes to show</div>;
  if (feed) {
    const data = feed
      .map(f => {
        return { ...f, datetime: GeneralUtil.formatDateTime(f.timestamp) };
      })
      .filter(
        f =>
          filterText === '' ||
          (f.content && f.content.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())) ||
          (f.author && f.author.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())) ||
          (f.uri && f.uri.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase()))
      );
    contents = (
      <DataTable
        title="Notes"
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        striped
        progressPending={pending}
        subHeader
        subHeaderComponent={subHeaderComponentMemo}
      />
    );
  } else if (error) {
    contents = <Error>There was an error loading the notes: {error}</Error>;
  }
  return <div className={styles.container}>{contents}</div>;
};

projectNotes.propTypes = {
  project: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default projectNotes;
```

All other packages are updated to there latest versions, except React itself, which is currently at v17, updating it will cause many breaking changes in my project, so, please avoid giving a solution that includes updating it, if possible.
It'd also be great if someone explains or points out the root cause of this error.